# Fetch data from hidden table using Selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fetch the station information from the website:
https://indiarailinfo.com/atlas

The table I'm trying to fetch is a hidden table which only appears on entering text in the text box
[Hidden table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPSGQ.png)
The below is the code of the div containing the required table (table class='dropdowntable")

```
<div style="top: 165px; left: 721px; display: none;" class="list hideslow">
<span style="display:none">LappGetStationList/nzm/0/1/0?&amp;date=1601890451781&amp;seq=9</span>
<table class="dropdowntable" numrows="1" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr class="rowM1" rownum="0"><td style="display:none">748</td><td class="rcol" nowrap=""><span><span class="listmatch">NZM</span></span></td><td class="icol" nowrap=""><span>Hazrat Nizamuddin</span></td><td class="jcol" nowrap=""><span>NR-Old Delhi Div</span></td><td style="display:none;">NZM/Hazrat Nizamuddin</td></tr><tr class="rowm2" rownum="0"><td style="display:none">748</td><td><span nowrap="">&nbsp;</span></td><td colspan="2" nowrap=""><span>Nizamuddin East/Sarai KaleKhan Bus Terminal 110013 Delhi NCT</span></td><td style="display:none">NZM/Hazrat Nizamuddin</td></tr><tr><td class="listfooter" colspan="5"><span width="10%" class="listfooterhidden">prev</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span width="10%" class="listfooterhidden">next</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tbody></table>

</div>
```

I have tried searching the table by class, but did't work. Any suggestions are welcome.

**Update 1:**

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()    
driver.get('https://indiarailinfo.com/atlas')
searchBox = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'TrkStnListBox')
searchBox.send_keys(code)
searchBox.click()
```

Approaches that I've tried:

```
1.dropDownTable = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,'LappGetStationList')
2.dropDownTable = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'list hideslow')
```

Now the following is where I'm having problems:

```
# hidden = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//input[@id='']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style','visibility:visible;');", hidden)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", dropDownTable)
dropDownTableBody = dropDownTable.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'tbody')
for entry in dropDownTableBody.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'tr'):
        if entry.get_attribute('rownum')==0 and entry.get_attribute('class')=='rowM1':
            for item in entry.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'td'):
                if item.get_attribute('class')=='icol':
                    station.update({
                        'STATION NAME' : decodeText(item)
                    })
                if item.get_attribute('class')=='jcol':
                    list = decodeText(item).split('-')
                    division = list[1][:list[1].find('Div')]
                    station.update({
                        'RAILWAY ZONE' : list[0],
                        'RAILWAY DIVISION' : division
                    })
            print(station)
```

Comment: your code will be helpful in determining what is wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with `chrome` browser hope this will works for `FF` browser as well.

Once insert text in the search box you need to wait for table to populate it is autosuggest box.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`()
Some of the table data are hidden so instead text use `get_attribute("textContent")`

**Code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://indiarailinfo.com/atlas")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"TrkStnListBox"))).send_keys("nzm")
table=WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'table.dropdowntable')))
for row in table.find_elements_by_xpath("./tbody/tr")[:2]:
    for col in row.find_elements_by_xpath("./td"):
        print(col.get_attribute("textContent"))
```

**Console Output:**

```
748
NZM
Hazrat Nizamuddin
NR-Old Delhi Div
NZM/Hazrat Nizamuddin
748
 
Nizamuddin East/Sarai KaleKhan Bus Terminal 110013 Delhi NCT
NZM/Hazrat Nizamuddin
```

Hope this is what you after.

Comment: Thanks!! That worked like a charm. Shaking my head as to why didn't think of implementing wait.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fetch the table with

```
# Go to the website
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://indiarailinfo.com/atlas")

# Send the search term
driver.find_element(By.ID, "TrkStnListBox").send_keys("nzm")
time.sleep(1)

# Read the Table
el = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "dropdowntable")
```

But I could not reach the information in the table even after searching for "td" and "span" tags in the `el` variable. Maybe someone can take it from here.

Edit: Added a sleep comment to make sure that table is ready.

Comment: Is this working for you? I'm getting unable to locate element

Comment: Yepi it's working for me. Can you see a Firefox (or Chrome if you are using that) window opening and writing "nzm" to the search box?

Comment: Well that's not exactly "working", fetching the table throws an element not found exception, other stuff does work, yes.

Comment: Sometimes it works and sometimes it didn't. I've added a sleep comment to fix that.